# Arithmetic triangle and choices

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

In regards to the arithmetic triangle:

```
   1  
 1   1   
1  2  1 etc
```

we know that it is a way to calculate the binomial coefficients or number of choices $C(n,r)$.

So I understand that there is only $1$ way to choose a set of size $0$ from an empty set and that is what the $1$ at the top of the triangle shows.
Also there is $1$ way to choose a set of size $0$ from any set hence each row starts with $1$. Each row is built on the previous one and I am confused with the logic for $2$, in the center of the third line.

Basically that $2$ means that there are $2$ ways to pick a single person from a pair, but this $2$ is the sum of the ones in the first row i.e. $1$ way to choose a set of size $0$ and $1$ way to choose one person from a set of one.
But summing these two with this meaning does not make sense to me i.e. that the number of ways to pick a single person from a pair is the number of ways to pick $0$ persons from an empty set plus the number of ways to pick $1$ person from a pair.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: The relevant identity is $\binom nk=\binom {n-1}{k-1}+\binom {n-1}k$.  The logic being, look at the choices containing object $n$ and those which don't.  There are $\binom {n-1}{k-1}$ of the first type, and $\binom {n-1}k$ of the second type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be more helpful to think about the general case first: $\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r + 1} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}$. (This is the combinatorial formula behind the condition that a number in the triangle is the sum of the two numbers above it.)

To explain this formula, imagine you have people numbered $1, 2, \dots, n + 1$, and that you want to choose a subset of $r + 1$ of them. The key idea is that you will include person $n + 1$ or you won’t. If you don’t include person $n + 1$, then you’re choosing a $(r + 1)$-subset from $n$ people, i.e. $\binom{n}{r + 1}$. If you do include person $n + 1$, then you have to choose $r$ more people from $n$ people, i.e. $\binom{n}{r}$. The “either/or” setup implies that the total number of subsets $\binom{n+1}{r+1}$ is the sum of these two binomial coefficients.

Now as for your special case: $\binom{2}{1} = \binom{1}{0} + \binom{1}{1}$, the people are named $1$ and $2$, and we want to choose just 1 of them. Your subset either contains person 2 or it doesn’t. If it doesn’t, we get the $\binom{1}{1} = 1$ term as we are forced to take person 1. If the subset does contain person 2, then we choose $0$ people from a set of size 1, i.e. the $\binom{1}{0}$ term.

Comment: You said contraction when you meant condition.

Comment: "If the subset does contain two" I think you mean "If the subset does contain person $2$"?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! Does the explanation help your misunderstanding @Jim?

Comment: Yes very helpful thank you very much! One last question. Instead of thinking to include/not include $n + 1$ could we use the same logic for person $1$ or a random person $i$? Why specifically the last person?

Comment: Yes, any distinguished person will do the trick. I choose $n + 1$ because it’s visually clear they’re the odd person out.